EEG Time Domain Features Selection
I am currently working on EEG data and trying to classify it. I was wondering if it was okay to use each time step as feature. I doesn't seem right for me but i'm having good results so I'm a bit lost.
I have 16 channels and 300 records, each record corresponds to one of the 4 labels. I started on the time domain because I read that this domain can be used for classification (alongside the other domains). I did some preprocessing like filtering, but I was thinking about something: is it acceptable to use each channel as observations and the "EEG time series" as features, so that each feature would be a time step?
For example if my recording is 2 seconds long and i have a value each 0.008 seconds, i would have 2 / 0.008 = 250 features
